# Null pointer dereference crash in _Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase when using std::map

Tags: android, c++, tizen

My program uses std::map to store some information along with some non-duplicated keys. This map is protected by one std::mutex. I use std::lock_guard for scope locking at the beginning of the methods which perform **.insert** or **.erase (with iterator)** on map.

I am not locking mutex only in the methods where I perform **.find** and use that iterator to get some information what I need. Do I need to protect map if I am just executing **.find** also?

Problem is when I run my program for few hours continuously which makes lot of .insert and .erase operation at some point my program crashes at.

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xc
Cause: null pointer dereference
#00 pc 00063d62 lib/arm/libgnustl_shared.so (_ZSt28_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erasePSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseRS_+137)
```

I don't understand how it's crashing when the code for finding an item and erasing it by iterator is protected by locked mutex. This happens on android.

Same code is crashing on Tizen too at

```
#0  std::_Rb_tree_rebalance_for_erase (__z=0x68bc78, __header=...) at /usr/src/debug/gcc-6.2.1/obj/armv7l-tizen-linux-gnueabi/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/../../../../../libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/tree.cc:415
```

Comment: Since you are using a mutex, I presume the code is multithreaded.  If you do a find while another thread is concurrently mutating the std::map, at some point I'd expect the program to crash (which jibes with the behavior you are experiencing).

Answer (score 1):

A program has a **data race** when more than one thread accesses the same object and **at least one** of those threads modifies the value of the object. So the code in the question has a data race, since readers can access the data while another thread is modifying it. A program that has a data race has undefined behavior.

The fix for a data race is to prevent multiple simultaneous access to the same object, either by using atomic accesses (hard) or by using a mutex (easier, but possibly slower). The simplest solution here is to guard **every** operation on the tree with the same mutex.

Even then, preventing a data race does **not** guarantee correctness. For example:

```
int sz = my_vector.size();
for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
    // do something with my_vector[i]
```

Using a mutex in `size()` and `operator[]` isn't enough; another thread might remove an element from the vector, and as a result, `sz` would be wrong, and the loop would go off the end of the vector.

Comment: Agree. we have to protect read operation too. But in my case crash should have appeared in the code which does the read part, but it crashed in erase . I am sure that my read part does not do operation which changes the map.

Comment: @Harish -- fix the problem. If the symptoms still occur, come back with a new question.